# MYSQL: Average count from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, average

I am trying to average the number of opens per recipient per mailing.

I am hoping to return something like this:

```
Mailing     Avg Open Per  
1           1.3  
2           3.4  
3           0.5
```

I have three tables. Below are the relevant columns

**Mailing M**
Three mailing types.
m_id: ID for each mailing
m_name: Name of each of three mailings

**Mailing Received MR**
u_id: Person who received mailing (multiple users can receive multiple mailings)
m_id: FK

**Mailing Open Type MOT***
Open/Click actions
muo_id: identifier for user open/clicks
muo_type_id: 1=click 2=open
u_id: FK

Here is what I have tried, among other things:

```
SELECT m.m_id, AVG(CASE WHEN muo_type_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS "Avg Open"
FROM mailing m
Left join
 mailing_received mr
on mr.m_id = m.m_id
Left join
mailing_open_type mot 
ON mr.u_id = mot.u_id
GROUP BY m.m_id;
```

Edit. Also tried this:

```
SELECT m.m_id, AVG(N) AS A,
(SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN mot.muo_type_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS N
FROM mailing m LEFT JOIN mailing_received mr ON m.m_id = mr.mailing_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN mailing_open_type mot
ON mr.u_id = mot.u_id
GROUP BY mr.u_id) as B;
```

Still no luck.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about using the 1st query you tried with a slight change like : `... AVG(CASE WHEN muo_type_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ...` (notice the `ELSE 0` part)

Comment: Well, how about that. It worked. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, try to simply add `.. ELSE 0 ..` to the 1st query you tried :

```
SELECT m.m_id, AVG(CASE WHEN muo_type_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Avg Open"
FROM mailing m
Left join
 mailing_received mr
on mr.m_id = m.m_id
Left join
mailing_open_type mot 
ON mr.u_id = mot.u_id
GROUP BY m.m_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how long it would have taken me to find that error.

Comment: you're welcome. Good to see this simple fix can solve the problem.